# Add a custom class from 2 different input in proper way

Tags: php, wordpress

I am newby on php. I re-write a code to add a custom class, but always got an error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in D:\MYWEB\InstantWP_4.3.1\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\js_composer\include\templates\shortcodes\vc_column.php on line 41

My code is like this:

```
 if (vc_shortcode_custom_css_has_property( $css, array('border', 'background') )) {
$css_classes[]='vc_col-has-fill'; 
 }

  $wrapper_attributes = array();

 $css_class = preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', apply_filters( VC_SHORTCODE_CUSTOM_CSS_FILTER_TAG, implode( ' ', array_filter( $css_classes ) ), $this->settings['base'], $atts ) );
 $wrapper_attributes[] = 'class="' . esc_attr( trim( $css_class ) ) . '"';

 $output .= '<div ' . implode( ' ', $wrapper_attributes ) esc_attr( trim( vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css ) ) ). '>';
 $output .= '<div class="vc_column-inner">';
 $output .= '<div class="wpb_wrapper">';
 $output .= wpb_js_remove_wpautop( $content );
 $output .= '</div>';
 $output .= '</div>';
 $output .= '</div>';

 echo $output;
```

Line 41 is like this:

```
 $output .= '<div ' . implode( ' ', $wrapper_attributes ) esc_attr( trim( vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css ) ) ). '>';
```

Really appreciate for any help

Thank you

Comment: You're missing a period on that line, before "esc_attr": `$wrapper_attributes ) . esc_attr( `.  It might be helpful to grab an IDE that will highlight the source of syntax errors, if you're not using one already.

Comment: You might want to write this as a seperate plugin. Update VC and your code is gone, isn't it?

Comment: I want to change the custom class from second level (near inner-class) to first level.

Comment: Added periode as you said, error is dissappear, but new class trow outside the div. <br> <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-9 vc_col-has-fill" vc_custom_1458249333240> <br> it should be like this: <br> <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-9 vc_col-has-fill vc_custom_1458249333240">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent declared $output before you expand the variable.

Replace it with this:

```
 $output = '<div ' . implode( ' ', $wrapper_attributes ) esc_attr( trim( vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css ) ) ). '>';
```

or add it like this

```
$output = '';
$output .= '<div ' . implode( ' ', $wrapper_attributes ) esc_attr( trim( vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css ) ) ). '>';
```

Good luck :)
(We've all been there)

Comment: Unfortunatelly, same error like before.

Comment: Mentos spotted another error. Remove the dot in " .= " on line 41 and add it before esc_attr.

Unfortunately you have issues in how you build the css classes as well. But adding the dot before esc_attr and removing the . in .= on L41 will solve some of the issues.

Try echoing implode( ' ', $wrapper_attributes ) as well as esc_attr( trim( vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css ) ) ) to see where the fault is

Comment: error is dissappear, but new class throw outside the div. <br> <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-9 vc_col-has-fill" vc_custom_1458249333240> <br> it should be like this: <br> <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-9 vc_col-has-fill vc_custom_1458249333240">

Comment: Great idea. I am using your idea and work perfect. Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot "." between implode(...) and esc_attr(...) on line 41.

Line 41, should be:

```
$output .= '<div ' . implode( ' ', $wrapper_attributes ) . esc_attr( trim( vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css ) ) ). '>';
```

Comment: The error is dissappear, but new class trow outside the div. <br> <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-9 vc_col-has-fill" vc_custom_1458249333240> <br>
it should be like this: <br>
<div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-9 vc_col-has-fill vc_custom_1458249333240">